# Nested conditionals in makefiles

Tags: if-statement, makefile

A makefile here has nested if statements to assign variable values and targets to be built.
The current nested structure isn't really a nest - it is a series of if statements:
There isn't any use of else.

Is this because makefiles don't have an equivalent of elseIf?

Current structure (indentations added for readability in this post)

```
If condition x
    if condition x.x
        blah
    endif
    if condition x.y
        blah blah
    endif
endif
if condition y
    if condition y.x
        blah
    endif
    if condition y.y
        blah blah
    endif
endif
```

Pseudocod-ish version of desired structure:

```
If condition x
    if condition x.x
        blah
    else
    if condition x.y
        blah blah
    endif
else
if condition y
    if condition y.x
        blah
    else
    if condition y.y
        blah blah
    endif
endif
```

Comment: Which version of make are you using? If it is GNU make, are you referring to the `$(if...)` function or to the `ifeq`, `ifneq`, `ifdef` and `ifndef` conditionals?

Comment: GNU make 3.82
I'm referring to ifeq etc

Comment: You should update your question, then. And also maybe improve its title. The standard wording here is _make conditionals_, not _if else_.

Comment: And by the way, 3.82 is really old. If it is possible you should consider upgrading.

Comment: Unfortunately not possible - this is run on a corporate cluster system. :(

Answer (score 2):

Does this answer your question?

```
ifeq ($(VAR1),x)
    ifeq ($(VAR2),x)
        $(info x.x)
    else ifeq ($(VAR2),y)
        $(info x.y)
    endif
else ifeq ($(VAR1),y)
    ifeq ($(VAR2),x)
        $(info y.x)
    else ifeq ($(VAR2),y)
        $(info y.y)
    endif
endif

all:;
```

Demo:

```
$ make VAR1=x VAR2=y
x.y
make: 'all' is up to date.
```

But you can also:

```
ifeq ($(VAR1).$(VAR2),x.x)
    $(info x.x)
else ifeq ($(VAR1).$(VAR2),x.y)
    $(info x.y)
else ifeq ($(VAR1).$(VAR2),y.x)
    $(info y.x)
else ifeq ($(VAR1).$(VAR2),y.y)
    $(info y.y)
endif

all:;
```

Demo:

```
$ make VAR1=y VAR2=x
y.x
make: 'all' is up to date.
```

For more information the best source is the [GNU make manual, section *Syntax of Conditionals*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditional-Syntax).

Comment: Support for `else <conditional>` was added in GNU make 3.81, released in 2006, FYI, so 3.82 will have it.

Comment: Note: do not indent `ifeq` and friends with tabs (spaces are fine), as then they will be interpreted as shell commands, and your recipe will fail.

Comment: the "spaces"‌ not "tabs" hint was super useful! thanks.